# Get the selected values from a rich:select which is inside o a4j:repeat

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, dictionary, richfaces

I am using a `a4j:repeat` control to iterate throughtout a `Map<Object, List<MyType>>` list. The XHTML page displays both `h:outputText` and `rich:select` controls.

I loop throughout a `Map<String, List<Items>>` instance, to show a master-detail tables. In the `h:outputText` I show the master description and the `rich:select` shows the detail.

The code is as follows:

customer.xhtml

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{masterManagedBean.listMasterItems.entrySet().toArray()}"
var="itemsVar">
    <h:outputText value="#{itemsVar.key}" />
    <rich:select enableManualInput="true">
       <f:selectItems value="#{itemsVar.value}" id="itemsMenu" 
                var="itemsVarSelect"
                     itemLabel="#{itemsVarSelect.descriptionItems}"
                      itemValue="#{itemsVarSelect.idItems}" />
    </rich:select>
 </a4j:repeat>
```

This snippet works perfect. But, I don't have any idea how to gain the selected value from every `rich:select` generated by the repeater. Please guidance me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide an example (http://sscce.org) of your xhtml and the managed bean. What in detail do you want to achive, What is the exact current problem (exceptions, error messages)...

Comment: @L-Ray I posted a snippet below. Thanks in advance

Comment: As I understand, the `List<MyType>` is different for every Object, right?

Comment: @HumanoLegal The box you typed that information in is for answers. Remember that stackOverflow is not like a forum with conversation threads. You can edit your question to include additional information when necessary (L-Ray has already done so in this instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I would suggest not to use the datastructure `Map<String,List>` for the described case. Why not changing the Structure into a normal List of objects (`List<SelectionObject>`) with the `SelectionObject`-class holding:

- name/label
- possible values (as List or Array)
- selected value

So the JSF code would look something like

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{masterManagedBean.listMasterItems}"
    var="itemsVar">
    <h:outputText value="#{itemsVar.label}" />
    <rich:select enableManualInput="true" value="#{itemsVar.selectedValue}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{itemsVar.possibleValues}" id="itemsMenu" 
                var="itemsVarSelect"
                     itemLabel="#{itemsVarSelect.descriptionItems}"
                     itemValue="#{itemsVarSelect.idItems}" />
    </rich:select>
</a4j:repeat>
```

Any preparations/building for this object structure can be done e.g. in `getListMasterItems` (use some caching), the retrieval of the users data is done in the `action` of your submit-button, anyway. Just iterate through the list and read out the `selectedValue. If the answer is usable/helpful, please consider an upvote, confirm if it worked out for you.

Hope it helps...

Comment: It sounds a fair solution. So, I would need to create another class with approaching properties to mimic the Map<String, List<T>> structure. Every object in the list would have the selected value, right?

Comment: Nice, awesome feedback! Soo, "upvote"/"accept" and... start something new today. :-)